# Is there a 'sub-header' php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a loop in my Wordpress site that brings in the site/post title, category, and content ...

```
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <h3><?php the_category(', '); ?></h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
```

I want to add a sub-title/paragraph underneath the title that's unique to each post (so I can't just put it in an h tag in the post html)

Is there something I can add to the content of the post or something that can be pulled out/called for from it by the php in my html that I can style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, you'd want to look at Custom Fields. You can build these either programatically, or you can use a plugin. I'd recommend using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

For what you're asking about, I would add a simple text field to your posts via the plugin. For this example, let's say you called that field 'sub_title'. Let's assume that the field is set to NOT be required. In your page code, you would do this:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php if(get_field('sub_title')){ ?>
    <p><?php the_field('sub_title'); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<h3><?php the_category(', '); ?></h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

This will check to see if the custom field has any content inside it, and if so, create a p tag, place the content of the field, then close with the p tag.

Advanced Custom Fields has a large array of fields you could add to your posts/pages, and a nice filtering system to only display the fields on the posts/pages you want them on. For example, you could show the sub_title field only on posts that are in Category 01 if you'd like.

Comment: I was thinking something like that was the answer, I do have some custom fields being used currently, but that is just to change css on specific posts, I haven't used it to add/change content before thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would search for custom post types. That sounds like what you're trying to do.